# python-Twitter-api

Tags: python, api, twitter

```
import twitter

client = twitter.Api()

client = twitter.Api(username='uname', password='password')

update = client.PostUpdate('Tweetin from python!')
```

This is my code.
When i execute this program i get this error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The twitter module you're using doesn't have `username` and `password` arguments to the API constructor.  Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this tutorial [Twitter From the Command Line in Python Using OAuth](http://jeffmiller.github.com/2010/05/31/twitter-from-the-command-line-in-python-using-oauth)

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, you have to use OAuth, and specify keys and access tokens in the API constructor:
http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

```
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token', access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```